# Laravel - Save multiple fields as array instead of row

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have one to many relation tables. I want to insert child table data in array instead of rows.

**Mobile.php**

```
protected $fillable = ['mobile_id', 'mobile_name'];

public function models() {
    return $this->hasMany(Model::class, 'mobile_id');
}
```

**Model.php**

```
protected $fillable = ['model_name', 'mobile_id'
    ];
public function model()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Mobile::class, 'mobile_id');
}
```

**View**

```
Mobile Name: <input type="text" name="mobile_name">

Models:

<input type="text" name="model_name[]">
<button class="add_model">Add Model</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public function create(Request $request, Mobile $mob){
  $mob= new Mobile;
  $mob->mobile_name = request('mobile_name');

  for($i=0; $i < count(request('model_name')); $i++){
     $models = new Model;
     $models->model_name = request('model_name')[$i];

     $mob->models()->save($models);
     }
 $mob->save();
}
```

It's creates a new row for each mobile models inserted. But I want those models inserted in a single column `model_name` in an array line.

**I tried**

```
for($i=0; $i < count(request('model_name')); $i++){
  Size::create([
  'model_name' => request('model_name')[$i],
  'mobile_id' => $mob->id
  ]);
```

But it is also not working.

Comment: If you want to OneToMany relation you did well but if you don't want to create a row at RDBMS for each model so you want to create a column in "Mobile" entity which name is "model_name" and store the json string. 

I don't suggest you can with a field storing json value because updating can be a problem.

Comment: I saved data on each row previously. Bu could not update later (delete/add dynamic rows). So I decided to store as json thinking I can update.

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize the data before saving it in the database.Create the model instance outside the for loop.Here is the working code.

```
   public function create(Request $request, Mobile $mob){
      $mob= new Mobile;
      $mob->mobile_name = $request('mobile_name');
      $models = new Model;
      $arr=[];
      for($i=0; $i < count($request('model_name')); $i++){
         array_push($arr, $request('model_name')[$i]);
         }
      serialize($arr);
      $models->model_name =$arr;
      $mob->models()->save($models);
     $mob->save();
    }
```

In the model.php, add the below code

```
protected $casts = [
      'model_name ' => 'array',
]
```

Comment: It throws ```Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given,...```

Comment: Add this in your `Model.php`
    protected $casts = [
     'model_name' => 'array',
    ];

Comment: Not worked. I still saves only one model_name. [My column data type is string. I can't change it to json due to error]

Comment: Still the same error. ``Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in ``

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your schema table, because you need to achieve this first :

```
//  Migrations 
$table->json('model_name');
```

That way you can persist many `model_name` in one row using one array.

Comment: Should I change ``$table->string('model_name')`` to ``$table->json('model_name')`` in migration file? Then?

Comment: Yes ! from that path you can get what you want. Hope this help you

Comment: It is now saved as ``["model_1","model_2","model_3"].`` How can I display this on view properly? And update the value later from Controller?

Comment: To display it you need to decode your data from your database `$array = json_decode($model->model_name, true)` then use a loop to show each name. To update it you simply need to encode it before going with a loop.

Comment: Should I put this on Controller or View? I tried ``$array = json_decode($model->model_name, true);`` on controller and ``@foreach($models as $mod){ {{ $mod->model_name }} }`` but it shows ``htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ``

Comment: Both, I don't know the structure of your json just try to debug and fix it but the error tells you that you have an array and you can't use `{{...}}` to show an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167544/discussion-between-yassine-beloued-and-universal).

Answer (score 0):

Try this 100% working i have deployed .

```
foreach($request->model_name as $item => $value)
$data[$value]=array(
    'mobile_name'=>$request->mobile_name,
    'model_name'=>$value,
    
);

Mobile::insert($data); // Eloquent approach
```